# Android Studio - No matching client found for package name ''

Tags: java, android

I have imported modules(multiple projects).
after importing them the sync was perfect but then when tried running the app , it showed this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrmxK.png)

here is my build.gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.secondyr"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearCivil')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearCs')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearElectronics')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearElectronicsandTelecom')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearProd')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearMech')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearTextile')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearIT')
implementation project(path: ':SecondYearETC')
```

}

I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow but i int understand .
i read about this solution to change the package name in .json file to the  package name in manisfest , i didnt understand which one to change becuase since there were many package name's

Comment: if you are using firebase , make sure you have added  the gson service file generated by firebase to your project

Answer (score 2):

Check your package name on your google-services.json it should be same with your local package name of your app

**Something like this**

```
"client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:6596814400689:android:65d6f25f5006145",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.my.app.package.name"
    }
```

Comment: since i have imported 9 projects. there are 9 package name's... so am i suppose to change all those package name's ??

Comment: I'm  really not sure how you're carrying out your task but if your using modules from different projects all is still under your own created project, so your project should still have only one package name. just do a thorough refactor on your project

Comment: I was not able to solve this problem . Instead i just created a new project and imported all other projects as libraries  . This actually worked . This is how i resolved the problem

Comment: Thank you anyways for your response and help . I appreciate that